# ASP.net MVC not updating dropdownlist values in subsequent post after validation fails with ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a View with 2 submit buttons.The controller has subsequent Post methods for each. The first button only saves certain fields and does not require any validation, the other field validates the whole form (including the fields the first button saves) and then only submit the page.

In the controller, I have modelstate.AddError methods set up for validating form fields. When the validation fails on a few dropdownlist, MVC seems to ignore them in subsequent post initiated from the first button. Failed dropdown list values are neither captured in modelstate, or model or FormCollection. Is there a way I can get the updated value for certain fields(few of which had failed validation in the first post) even when some other fields are not updated.

Comment: Worry less about MVC and more about HTML. Did the generated HTML change after validation failure? How did the data which was posted change from one button click to the next? Answer those two questions, and you'll no doubt find that the one is related to the other.

Comment: Yes the data did change. The no of fields that were posted back did not include the field values that were invalid but were fixed before the 2nd post.

Comment: What type of form field contained those values? Form POST doesn't change the fields posted based on whether they are valid or not. Possibly, something else changed which fields were posted.

Comment: These fields are Dropdownlist that use html and kendo MVC wrappers...
                                        @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.q).BindTo(ViewBag.AssignedTo)

Comment: It doesn't make sense that a field would post or not based on whether there are validation errors. Try for a different explanation.

Comment: Ok seems like since I was using the same key for dropdown and associated validation error...the post data was referring to the validation error key. After I changed it, it seems to all work.

Comment: And this is why to post example code.